# Ubuntu 16: Confusion regarding Python 2.7 and Python 3.x

Tags: apt, python, python3, pip, python-2.7

I have gone through the related questions and their answers. Still I am asking this question.

1. If a change the alias to Python 3.x, will the system break.
2. There are two `pip` files in`\usr\bin` directory. `pip` and `pip2`. I don't know which one to use to get modules and packages.
3. `pandas` is installed but `import pandas` in Python 2 works properly. But not in Python 3.x
4. `pip install pandas` gives an error while `pip2 install pandas` is telling that `pandas` is already installed.

Due to the above reasons, I am not able to work in Python in my Linux box (Ubuntu 16.0), but in Windows I have only `Python3`, the works goes smooth.

Kindly clarify my doubt and tell the right way to go about.

Comment: What does `pip --version` return?

Comment: Ubuntu releases are *yy.mm* for major releases, only speciality releases use *year* (eg. Ubuntu Core 16 for IoT appliances/devices). There is no Ubuntu 16.0 as 0 is an invalid month

Comment: I shall reply later, as I don't  have my laptop with me right now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the following:

```
pip --version
```

Here is the output I get. Notice Python version mentioned within parenthesis.

```
pip 19.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

To illustrate further, you have pip for Python 2.x and for Python 3.x. The following is output excerpts from `apt-cache` searches on my Ubuntu box:

```
python-pip - alternative Python package installer
python3-pip - alternative Python package installer - Python 3 version of the package
```

So, ***if you have installed both above*** you can run pip for Python 2.x and for Python 3.x:

```
pip2 --version
pip 19.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)

pip --version
pip 19.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

Notice how `pip` on my box defaults to `pip3` (the output in the last line is the same as the first output in the beginning of this answer.)

Hope this helps you.